# Pandas/Python - merging 2 dataframes, using columns as data and rows as extra rows in original dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes, as follows

df (contains the index, the title of the bank, the last changed date of the bank savings APR and the uid, which is the same as the index, I was experimenting with matching on that column)

| index | title | last_changed_friendly | uid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e |
| af1d2fcd-5f09-4611-80c9-564fb346c875 | Bank Purely Money Market | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | af1d2fcd-5f09-4611-80c9-564fb346c875 |

tempdf (contains the index, all records in tempdf match the uid/index of the uid/index in df, the date which the APR was retrieved and finally a reference to the text file that contains the APR itself)

| uid | time_date_friendly | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:00:01 | b866e03c-928b-4ea0-a293-5ae69fe88cfc.txt |
| 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:01:29 | 86c5ef05-fac0-4177-a347-8585299ecb88.txt |
| 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 99c911bc-86be-4bd4-afdd-89acd279aaa1.txt |

I am trying to create the following dataframe from the above

| index | title | last_changed_friendly | uid | time_date_friendly | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:00:01 | b866e03c-928b-4ea0-a293-5ae69fe88cfc.txt |
| 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:01:29 | 86c5ef05-fac0-4177-a347-8585299ecb88.txt |
| 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 99c911bc-86be-4bd4-afdd-89acd279aaa1.txt |

I have tried various iterations of join, concat and merge and I get the closest with the following:

`df = tempdf.merge(df,how='left', left_on='uid', right_on='uid')`

But that creates 9 rows, as opposed to the 3 that I am trying to get to, as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e", "Republic Bank Digital Money Market", "2023-02-28 22:59:49", "55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e"],
    ["af1d2fcd-5f09-4611-80c9-564fb346c875", "Bank Purely Money Market", "1970-01-01 00:00:00", "af1d2fcd-5f09-4611-80c9-564fb346c875"],
], columns = ["index", "title", "last_changed_friendly", "uid"])
```

|  | index | title | last_changed_friendly | uid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e |
| 1 | af1d2fcd-5f09-4611-80c9-564fb346c875 | Bank Purely Money Market | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | af1d2fcd-5f09-4611-80c9-564fb346c875 |

```py
tempdf = pd.DataFrame([
    ["55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e", "2023-02-18 19:00:01", "b866e03c-928b-4ea0-a293-5ae69fe88cfc.txt"],
    ["55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e", "2023-02-18 19:01:29", "86c5ef05-fac0-4177-a347-8585299ecb88.txt"],
    ["55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e", "2023-02-28 22:59:49", "99c911bc-86be-4bd4-afdd-89acd279aaa1.txt"],
], columns=["uid", "time_date_friendly", "Reference"])
```

|  | uid | time_date_friendly | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:00:01 | b866e03c-928b-4ea0-a293-5ae69fe88cfc.txt |
| 1 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:01:29 | 86c5ef05-fac0-4177-a347-8585299ecb88.txt |
| 2 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 99c911bc-86be-4bd4-afdd-89acd279aaa1.txt |

```py
df.merge(tempdf, on='uid')
```

|  | index | title | last_changed_friendly | uid | time_date_friendly | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:00:01 | b866e03c-928b-4ea0-a293-5ae69fe88cfc.txt |
| 1 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-18 19:01:29 | 86c5ef05-fac0-4177-a347-8585299ecb88.txt |
| 2 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | Republic Bank Digital Money Market | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 55e0f3b0-aacb-48a6-b71c-2fe282eb6e2e | 2023-02-28 22:59:49 | 99c911bc-86be-4bd4-afdd-89acd279aaa1.txt |

Comment: Thank you, this worked - what I learned in the process was that `merged_df = pd.merge(df, tempdf, left_on='uid', right_on='uid')` is not the same as `df = pd.merge(df, tempdf, left_on='uid', right_on='uid')` as doing a 'print(df)` displays 9 records, but doing 'print(merged_df)` displays the correct 3 records. I am unclear why, but this in conjunction with the below answer has helped immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Try merging the two dataframes on the uid column and then filtering the resulting dataframe based on the last_changed_friendly and time_date_friendly columns.

code:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df, tempdf, on='uid')
filtered_df = merged_df[merged_df['last_changed_friendly'] == merged_df['time_date_friendly']]
```

This code first merges the two dataframes on the uid column using the pd.merge() function. The resulting dataframe will contain all columns from both dataframes. Then, we filter this merged dataframe to only include rows where the last_changed_friendly column matches the time_date_friendly column. This ensures that we only keep rows where the APR was last changed on the same date that we retrieved it.

Note that this assumes that the last_changed_friendly and time_date_friendly columns are in the same date format. If they are not, you may need to convert them to the same format before filtering the dataframe.

Comment: The OP has not asked for this filtering and the expected results does not use it.

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow, but this helped immensely in the next step, which is to filter out for only the latest record, so thank you. Not sure if I can upvote both answers, but will see how I can do this